# Angularjs Controller sets different value to object than assigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, rest

in one of the projects that I am working on, I am fetching Invoice Items from a REST API and filling them in their respective fields. But something unusual is happening. When i try to assign a float value sent from REST, angular assigns it as 0.

To explain my problem clearly , consider the following

```
$scope.commodities = {
    items: [],
    total: 0,
    total_gst: 0
};

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.output.data.length; i++) { //$scope.output is the response from REST API

    var itms = {};
    itms.item_description = $scope.output.data[i].item_description;
    itms.currency = $scope.output.data[i].currency;
    itms.amount = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].amount);
    itms.ex_rate = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].ex_rate);
    itms.tax = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].tax);
    itms.quantity = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].quantity);
    itms.total_without_gst = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].total_without_gst);
    itms.gst = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].gst);
    itms.total_with_gst = parseFloat($scope.output.data[i].total_with_gst);
    console.log(itms.total_without_gst); //displays correct value
    console.log(itms) //displays total_with_gst,total_without_gst as 0
    $scope.commodities.items.push(itms); 

}
```

REST API Response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "item_description": "Ocean freight",
            "currency": "USD",
            "tax": 0,
            "amount": 150,
            "ex_rate": 4.42,
            "quantity": 1,
            "total_without_gst": 663,
            "gst": 0,
            "total_with_gst": 663
        },
        {
            "item_description": "DG charges",
            "currency": "USD",
            "tax": 0,
            "amount": 80,
            "ex_rate": 4.42,
            "quantity": 1,
            "total_without_gst": 353.6,
            "gst": 0,
            "total_with_gst": 353.6
        }
    ]
}
```

I have attached the console screenshot for your reference
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I grabbed your code and ported to vanilla JS locally, and everything works fine. Show us how you are assigning the API response to `$scope.output`.

Comment: I am sorry guys. There is no error in this code. The problem was, i was initiating those values using ng-init.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment (need 50 rep), so I will put this up as an answer instead for now. From what I gathered from your data and the definition of parseFloat (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp), you are sending actual float values or numbers, however parseFloat parses float values from strings. Can you perhaps not just directly assign the float values?

Answer (score 0):

In Your case I guess the problem is with for loop which you are using,ideally if you are using angularjs then you should angular.forEach instead of normal for loop.

```
angular.forEach("$scope.output.data", function(object){

});
```

This is the fiddle link, I have used the same object which you are getting from REST and parsed it and displayed it on the html page.

This is the Link : [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0uzo3vtd/2/)

Approve the answer if this solution helps